# Parallel HTTP web crawler in Erlang

Tags: http, erlang

I'm coding on a simple web crawler and have generated a bunch gf static files I try to crawl by the code at bottom. I have two issues/questions I don't have an idea for:

1.) Looping over the sequence 1..200 throws me an error *exactly* after 100 pages have been crawled:

```
** exception error: no match of right hand side value {error,socket_closed_remotely}
     in function  erlang_test_01:fetch_page/1 (erlang_test_01.erl, line 11)
     in call from lists:foreach/2 (lists.erl, line 1262)
```

2.) How to parallelize the requests, e.g. 20 cincurrent reqs

```
-module(erlang_test_01).
-export([start/0]).

-define(BASE_URL, "http://46.4.117.69/").

to_url(Id) ->
  ?BASE_URL ++ io_lib:format("~p", [Id]).

fetch_page(Id) ->
  Uri = to_url(Id),
  {ok, {{_, Status, _}, _, Data}} = httpc:request(get, {Uri, []}, [], [{body_format,binary}]),
  Status,
  Data.

start() ->
  inets:start(),
  lists:foreach(fun(I) -> fetch_page(I) end, lists:seq(1, 200)).
```

Comment: maybe the server is closing any connection from you ip because you are making requests very fast and it may seem like a dos attack?

Comment: I'm running my own server and have root access to the box. Ruby Scripts fetching large amount of files work fine, also running the Erlang snippet above multiple times works fine, but every instance of that can only obtain 100 pages. Weird ...

Answer (score 6):

**1. Error message**

`socket_closed_remotely` indicates that the server closed the connection, maybe because you made too many requests in a short timespan.

**2. Parallellization**

Create 20 worker processes and one process holding the URL queue. Let each process ask the queue for a URL (by sending it a message). This way you can control the number of workers.

An even more "Erlangy" way is to spawn one process for *each* URL! The upside to this is that your code will be very straightforward. The downside is that you cannot control your bandwidth usage or number of connections to the same remote server in a simple way.